# Add social media link and professional link to CV

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

I'm pretty sure right now we can't add social media and professional links to our CV that made through developer story. Why can't we?

I really hope my recruiters can see my Stack Overflow link, GitHub link, etc., so it will help me getting hired. Am I missing this feature? Or will it be implemented in the future?